# how to work with Netbeans CVS over FTP

Tags: netbeans, cvs

I have small team that develop a PHP project with Netbeans and I want to use CVS to sync the source code between all team members and allow checkin/out.

I have a share hosting server with ftp account and I want to use it as a repository for CVS to store the source code, is it possible or I have to have ssh account ?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CVS inside a LAN, I've never seen access through FTP.

May I suggest you to use another Version control system? Which work very well over HTTP, like Subversion, Git or Mercurial?

That's what Google choosed for code hosting: http://code.google.com/hosting/